# Thunderbird spellcheck does not work when forwarding message

Tags: thunderbird, spell-check

I am using spellcheck (spellcheck as you type) in Thunderbird 68.8 on Debian Buster.

Normally, the spellcheck works fine (after [my previous problem has been solved](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/593975/155832)).

It works when composing new message, or replying to message. But when I am forwarding an email, it works sometimes and sometimes not.

After extensive trial and error, I was able to narrow down to problem to following:

When I click on the "Forward" button and the message compose window opens (with the original message below), and if I start typing on the second line (ie when I place my cursor on the second line), the spellcheck does not work. But when I place the cursor on the first line, it does work.

Looks like a bug in Thunderbird.

Is there any way to fix this problem?

Comment: @intika - I was able to narrow down this issue, so that it can be reproduced.

Comment: is this related to html vs text messages ? (not on the reply, but the original message)

Comment: @intika - I can reproduce this problem for any message, regardless of format. Every time I start replying on line nr. 2 (click with mouse cursor on line 2 and start typing). This is really bizarre.

Comment: i know that forward and reply action does by default create an "edition" on html format even if you are sending all your message on text format... I do have a custom addon that  add some new bottons (reply and forward) in text mode... I am pretty sure that while using that addon i am not impacted by the problem you described... let me know if you need those addons... they are not published.

Comment: You should really file a bug-report with Mozilla. I would think that the problem is by design, the developer assuming that the user's preferred method for forwarding is as-is. For updating `omni.ja`, see [this post](https://shallowsky.com/blog/tech/web/modifying-omni.ja.html). However, if it's truly there, finding where is the real challenge.

Comment: @harrymc - thank you. But even in best case scenario, bug-report to Mozilla will only fix it in some distant future version. I need this fixed in my current version.

Answer (score 2):

Saved out an HTML message just after clicking the forward button, and found that the message initially looks like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    <br>
    <div class="moz-forward-container"><br>
      <br>
      -------- Forwarded Message --------
```

Since the second and third lines fall within the "moz-forward-container" div, and TB apparently assumes anything within that div is forwarded content and so skips spellchecking it, there'd be no spellchecking for anything written on those lines.

Not exactly a bug, but certainly not great design.

Checking the Config Editor, there isn't any option for changing the number of blank lines in a new forwarded message. Unless there's some template file or other external data I'm not aware of upon which forwarded message structure is based, it looks like it can't be fixed without modifying the TB source code.

Comment: by `modifying the TB source code` you mean actual source code that needs to be recompiled, or could this be fixed by extracting `omni.ja`, making changes, and ziping again back?

Comment: I don't know. As [Mozilla's omni.ja doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/About_omni.ja_%28formerly_omni.jar%29) indicates, many of Thunderbird's internal parts have been moved into `omni.ja` from either standalone files or sets of JAR files. So, it could be either. One would have to dig through the internals to find what exactly needs to be changed. But since it's not compiled, `omni.ja` would be a good place to start looking.

Answer (score 0):

If spell-checking of forwarded text is important, I have found one way of
forcing it, but in a somewhat unsatisfactory way:

- Click the Thunderbird menu *Tools > Options*
- Enter the "Composition" section
- Check the option "Check spelling before sending".

This will invoke, when Send is clicked, the old "Check Spelling" dialog,
where you may correct the spelling one word at a time, or click "Send" to send as-is. The currently treated word in the dialog will be highlighted inside the
message text.